# Updating libpng on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, imagemagick, shared-libraries

I had a need to run the Ubuntu `libpng` utility `convert`, and when I did I got an error message that my version of `libpng` was out of date and had to be updated. So, I went the usual route of `apt-get install`, but for reasons I now no longer remember, this didn't solve the problem. This is where things got messy.

I downloaded the source for `libpng`, did a make, and a make install. While a shareable library was created in `/usr/local/lib`, convert now reports:

```
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libpng.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

On the advice of a helpful person elsewhere on StackExchange, I tried `apt-get install` again, attempting to get and install the packages `libpng12-dev` and `libpng12-0`. However, both attempts generated the messages

```
libpng12-dev is already the newest version
libpng12-0 is already the newest version
```

...and so nothing was installed. Probably my clumsy attempts with making the source have screwed things up. Is there some way I clean things up? For example, installing an older version of libpng and then installing the latest version?

Later:

On dogbert's suggestion, I consulted the article at https://www.debian-administration.org/article/176/Reinstalling_packages_to_fix_problems and discovered that I could force the deletion of a package without blowing away all the dependent packages as well:

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends libpng12-0
```

So, I did that, and then re-installed `libpng12-0`. However, `convert` still reports the same error. Okay, maybe I need to reinstall `convert` since possibly the `libpng12-0` library is not where it is expected to be. `convert` is part of `imagemagick`, so I uninstalled it. However, `convert` was still available at the command line, so uninstalling `imagemagick` doesn't get rid of it. Re-installed `imagemagick`. Same results: `convert` still complains that it can't find `libpng.so.2`.

Searched the entire hard drive and found that no file `libpng.so*`exists anywhere. Apparently installing the package isn't creating the needed file.

Comment: This should help you out buddy: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/176/Reinstalling_packages_to_fix_problems. This too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140247/force-install-apt-get

Answer (score 0):

libpng.so.2 is supposed to be the shared library for libpng-1.0.x (current version is 1.0.63).  You have "convert" (part of imagemagick) that apparently was built with libpng-1.0.x, so you need to remove and reinstall imagemagick via apt-get. Once that is working, you can try again to install a newer version of imagemagick, from imagemagick.org, which should work ok with libpng12.